# How to cordon a Kubernetes node using golang client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to use golang Kubernetes client SDK to cordon specific nodes in my Kubernetes cluster.

According to other posts, I need to pass the following:

```
PATCH /api/v1/nodes/node-name

Request Body: {"spec":{"unschedulable":true}} Content-Type: "application/strategic-merge-patch+json"
```

However, I am not familiar with how to pass that.

I have the following, but not sure if those values are correct

```
type patchStringValue struct {
    Op    string `json:"op"`
    Path  string `json:"path"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func k8NodeCordon() {
    clientSet := k8ClientInit()

    payload := []patchStringValue{{
        Op:    "replace",
        Path:  "/spec/unschedulable",
        Value: "true",
    }}
    payloadBytes, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    _, err := clientSet.
        CoreV1().Nodes().Patch()
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add the following:

```golang
_, err := clientSet.CoreV1().Nodes().Patch("<node_name>", types.JSONPatchType, payloadBytes)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
type patchStringValue struct {
    Op    string `json:"op"`
    Path  string `json:"path"`
    Value bool   `json:"value"`
}

func k8NodeCordon() {
    clientSet := k8ClientInit()

    payload := []patchStringValue{{
        Op:    "replace",
        Path:  "/spec/unschedulable",
        Value: true,
    }}
    payloadBytes, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    _, err := clientSet.CoreV1().Nodes().Patch("<node_name>", types.JSONPatchType, payloadBytes)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please consider giving some explanation about the the cause of the problem and how your answer solves it.

Comment: `d.ClientSet.CoreV1().Nodes().Patch(context.TODO(), nodeName, types.JSONPatchType, payloadBytes, metav1.PatchOptions{})` - you need add context and options